# recover email with facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have this script and it works pretty good. The only problem I'm having is that I can't recover the email address, it comes empty:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'appid','secret' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('URL');
try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
// When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
$fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
$femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
/* ---- Session Variables -----*/
$_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;
$_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
$_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
 header("Location: index.php");
} else {
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

I'm getting $fbid and $fbfullname correctly but my $femail is empty. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Email requires the extended permission scope `user_email` to be requested and approved by the user. It's not accessible by default.

Comment: how can I add it?

Comment: $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));

Comment: I solved like this